# How to convert data into little endian format?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

```
var val = 1240;
```

convert into little endian formate swift 3

Ex: `1500 (0x5DC)` to `0xDC050000`

Comment: newValue = [0x00, 0xC0, 0x03, 0x00] ----> How its convert into little endian? i need o/p as 0003C000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                let timeDevide = self.setmiliSecond/100
                var newTime = UInt32(littleEndian: timeDevide)
                let arrayTime = withUnsafeBytes(of: &newTime) 
                 {Array($0)}
                let timeDelayValue = [0x0B] + arrayTime
```

Comment: Thanx @Deepak, It Does Work for me, only it send a deprecated warning. "withUnsafeMutableBytes' is deprecated: use withUnsafeMutableBytes<R>(_: (UnsafeMutableRawBufferPointer) throws -> R) rethrows -> R instead". kindly can you write another update for swift 5 too, thanx.

Answer (score 6):

```
let value = UInt16(bigEndian: 1500)

print(String(format:"%04X", value.bigEndian)) //05DC
print(String(format:"%04X", value.littleEndian)) //DC05
```

Make sure you are actually using the `bigEndian` initializer.

With 32-bit integers:

```
let value = UInt32(bigEndian: 1500)

print(String(format:"%08X", value.bigEndian)) //000005DC
print(String(format:"%08X", value.littleEndian)) //DC050000
```

Comment: Thanks, if i get "05DC0000" output. what can do?

Comment: Added 32-bit version

Comment: One more que. about string to data, i need to send 3 diff array of same counts. ex: Hello How are you? Hello (0x01) line 1 char 1-6 How ar (0x02) Ho (cha 7-8 of line-1, w ar char 1-4 of line2) e you? (x03) Char 5-8 of line2 Hello How are you? Hello (0x01) line 1 char 1-6 How ar (0x02) Ho (cha 7-8 of line-1, w ar char 1-4 of line2) e you? (x03) Char 5-8 of line2      --- how to set in 3 arrays.

Comment: newValue = [0x00, 0xC0, 0x03, 0x00] ----> How its convert into little endian? i need o/p as 0003C000

Answer (score 5):

If you want 1500 as an array of bytes in little-endian order:

```
var value = UInt32(littleEndian: 1500)

let array = withUnsafeBytes(of: &value) { Array($0) }
```

If you want that as a `Data`:

```
let data = Data(array)
```

Or, if you really wanted that as a hex string:

```
let string = array.map { String(format: "%02x", $0) }.joined()
```

Comment: Also thank you for an array of bytes. its work proper.

Comment: 0x0C01 + DC050000 what can i do?

Comment: How to convert [0xDC, 0x05, 0x00, 0x00]

Comment: 0x0C01(write value in BLE device) is value to merge with DC050000 [0x0C, 0X01, 0xDC, 0x05, 0x00, 0x00].

Comment: if `array` contains the `[0xdc, 0x05, 0x00, 0x00]`, then `let array2 = [0x0c, 0x01] + array` would represent the six bytes, namely `0x0c` and `0x01` followed by the other four bytes. And you can then convert that to a `Data`, too, if you need, e.g. `let data2 = Data(array2)`.

Comment: How can create [0x0C, 0X01, 0xDC, 0x05, 0x00, 0x00] from 0x0C01 and DC050000, this array is value for write value BLE characteristic.

Comment: You saw how to create `[0xDC, 0x05, 0x00, 0x00]` from 1500, above, right? The same is for creating array of `[0x0c, 0x01]` from `0x0C01` (except you'd use `UInt16` instead of `UInt32`). Then just append the two arrays together using `+`.

Comment: One more que. about string to data,  i need to send 3 diff array of same counts. ex: Hello How are you?
Hello (0x01) line 1 char 1-6
How ar (0x02) Ho (cha 7-8 of line-1, w ar char 1-4 of line2)
e you? (x03) Char 5-8 of line2
Hello How are you?
Hello (0x01) line 1 char 1-6
How ar (0x02) Ho (cha 7-8 of line-1, w ar char 1-4 of line2)
e you? (x03) Char 5-8 of line2

Comment: newValue = [0x00, 0xC0, 0x03, 0x00] ----> How its convert into little endian? i need o/p as 0003C000

Comment: The term "little endian" only makes sense when you're talking about converting an `Int` into binary format. But if you really had `let newValue: [UInt8] = [0x00, 0xC0, 0x03, 0x00]` and wanted to get it in the reverse order, you can reverse it with `let foo = Array(newValue.reversed())`. Or look at how you built the `newValue` array in the first place. For example, `var a = UInt32(littleEndian: 12_583_680)` or `var a = UInt32(littleEndian: 1 << 8 | 1 << 9 | 1 << 22 | 1 << 23)`, then `let b = withUnsafeBytes(of: &a) { Array($0) }`. It just depends upon what the source of the value was.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

extension String {
    func hexadecimal() -> Data? {
        var data = Data(capacity: count / 2)
        let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "[0-9a-f]{1,2}", options: .caseInsensitive)
        regex.enumerateMatches(in: self, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: utf16.count)) { match, _, _ in
            let byteString = (self as NSString).substring(with: match!.range)
            var num = UInt8(byteString, radix: 16)!
            data.append(&num, count: 1)
        }
        guard !data.isEmpty else { return nil }
        return data
    }
}


func convertInputValue<T: FixedWidthInteger>(_ inputValue: Data) -> T where T: CVarArg {
    let stride = MemoryLayout<T>.stride
    assert(inputValue.count % (stride / 2) == 0, "invalid pack size")

    let fwInt = T.init(littleEndian: inputValue.withUnsafeBytes { $0.pointee })
    let valuefwInt = String(format: "%0\(stride)x", fwInt).capitalized
    print(valuefwInt)
    return fwInt
}

var inputString = "479F"
var inputValue: Data! = inputString.hexadecimal()
let val: UInt16 = convertInputValue(inputValue) //9F47

inputString = "479F8253"
inputValue = inputString.hexadecimal()
let val2: UInt32 = convertInputValue(inputValue) //53829F47
```